# Integration of an infinitesimal part

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

In my EMF lecture, the professor first formulated the equation below for an infinitesimal part of a force and then integrated it. I can't explain this step with what I know from my math lectures. When integrating an equation, I would expect a '$\int_a^b dx$' (or some vectorial form of that) to be added to both sides but he just added the integral sign (no additional differential!). Furthermore, I would expect a change of dimension as a result of the integration (like e.g. acceleration integrated results in velocity) - accordingly, an integration of a force would not result in a force again. How can I explain what he did? I suspect that it is probably shorthand for some other integration.

$$d\vec{F}_{PP'}=\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\varrho(\vec{r}')\varrho(\vec{r})\frac{\vec{r}'-\vec{r}}{\lvert\vec{r}'-\vec{r}\rvert^3}dVdV'=-d\vec{F}_{P'P} \\ \implies \vec{F}=\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\int_V\int_V\varrho(\vec{r})\varrho(\vec{r}')\frac{\vec{r}-\vec{r}'}{\lvert\vec{r}-\vec{r}'\rvert^3}dV'dV=\vec{0}$$

**Edit** To simplify the question, essentially what I am asking is:

I know that
$$
f(x) = g(x)
\implies
\int_a^b f(x) \,dx = \int_a^b g(x) \,dx.
$$

But how do I explain that is valid:
$$
df = g(x)\,dh
\implies
f = \int_a^b g(x) \,dh
$$

Comment: You're a bit confused when you speak about acceleration: sure, if $a$ is the acceleration, then $\int a\ dt=v$, but if you just integrate $da$ you'll get $a$. So in your main question integrating a little bit of force over the solid gives the total force.

Comment: I see what you mean with integrating acceleration. But if $\int a\,dt$ gives me 'acceleration multiplied by time' (velocity) wouldn't $\int a\,da$ give me something like 'acceleration multiplied by acceleration' hence acceleration squared?

Comment: I did not say  $\int a\ da$ I said  $\int da$. In your main question is is just $\int_{V\times V} dF$.

Comment: Mathematicians are often not keen to separate off loose $dx$'s and maybe that's what's confusing you. I think this one is specially confusing because of having more $d$'s on the right that the left. It's so long since I did potential theory I can't quite sort this out for you.

Comment: I see, sorry for my misunderstanding.
No problem, thanks anyway!